# Unable to load dynamic library mongodb.so using AMPPS on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, lamp, xampp, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb dependency from composer for my laravel project and it needs mongodb driver installed.
I'm using AMPPS 3.6 on ubuntu 14.04 which by default has mongodb.so extension and also mongo.so, but my problem is when I get version of my php by running : `php -v`  I'm getting this error :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/ampps/php-7.0/lib/extensions/ext/mongodb.so' - libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/ampps/php-7.0/lib/extensions/ext/mongodb.so' - libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

when i want to see php modules by : `php -m` I can not see mongodb extention in the list of modules.

As you can see there is something related to `libssl.so.6` and I think this library is stopping me.

FYI : I'm using AMPPS 3.6 on mac OS sierra and it's working without any problem.

This is the list of my enabled php extention :

```
extension=bz2.so
extension=curl.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=intl.so
extension=imap.so
extension=ldap.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=exif.so      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=shmop.so
extension=soap.so
extension=sockets.so
extension=sqlite3.so
extension=tidy.so
extension=xsl.so
extension=gd.so
extension=zlib.so
extension=xmlrpc.so
extension=wddx.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=sysvshm.so
extension=sysvsem.so
extension=pcntl.so
extension=openssl.so
extension=mongodb.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=iconv.so
extension=ftp.so
extension=dba.so
extension=ctype.so
extension=calendar.so
extension=bcmath.so
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for this problem, I'm posting it here for other peoples to use it.

From the ldd command it looks like the binary is looking in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and not /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu where you found the symlink.

Try running these and see if you still get the same error:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.6

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.6
```

`ln -s` creates a symlink from the `libssl.so.1.0.0` binary to `libssl.so.6` filename in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory. `sudo` permissions are needed as `/lib` is a root directory.

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

1. From AMPPS Control Center -> PHP -> Settings icon (the wheel) -> Click PHP extension icon.
2. A window called "Extensions" pops up.
3. Simply uncheck and re-check everything and hit "Apply". That's all! Hassle free.

This probably automagically refreshes the symlinks...

Hope this helps.